# I need a secure laptop tethered to a mobile internet connection.

Tags: mobile, man-in-the-middle, surveillance

I invent things. Think energy, IT security algorithms, etc.

I'm actively targeted for information breaches by the largest corporations on the planet.

All paranoia aside...

I'd like a secure environment to develop software and other ideas before they hit the black market. I know all my current systems including my phone have been breached and I'd like a blank slate.

I need a fresh phone with anonymous, untraceable internet access, a fresh laptop, and I need to keep my budget under $1k. I like to work with linux and don't have any secure discs or copies available. Ideally, the laptop will just become a ssh terminal leashed to the phones internet access where all data exchange is set to burst encrypted transmissions to a secure server somewhere in the US that will do all the heavy lifting. Consider AWS and Google servers unavailable. It won't be for facebook and porn.

How would you recommend I go about doing it? How would you do it?

How would you configure the software and what would your must haves be? Would be nice?

Comment: This may provide [some](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/09/how_to_remain_s.html) [answers](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/10/air_gaps.html)

Comment: The largest corporations on the planet want to hack you, but you only have $1k to spend to protect yourself?

Comment: Why not ssh from the phone itself? Why the laptop if the programming will be done on your server farm?